# How to get variable definition line number etc. using dbg metadata?

Tags: llvm, llvm-gcc, llvm-c++-api, llvm-ir

As far as I know, when I need to get the line number of a local variable I had to look for the  invocation of the `llvm.dbg.declare` intrinsics and get the dbg metadata(since `AllocaInst` itself does not contain any dbg info). However there seems no guarantee that this `CallInst` is the next instruction of the the `AllocaInst`, and I have to traverse the instruction in a specified function, which is inefficient. So I'm wondering whether there is a method for `AllocaInst` to get the `llvm.dbg.declare` instruction directly.

For example,in a src called `foo.c`:

```
int foo(){
     int a;
}
```

and the corresponding llvm ir:

```
define i32 @foo() nounwind {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32
  %a = alloca i32
  %"alloca point" = bitcast i32 0 to i32
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata !{i32* %a}, metadata !7), !dbg !9
  br label %return, !dbg !10

return:                                           ; preds = %entry
  %retval1 = load i32* %retval, !dbg !10                                                                                                     
  ret i32 %retval1, !dbg !10
}
......
!9 = metadata !{i32 3, i32 0, metadata !8, null}
```

If I need to know the line number of `int a;` defined in `foo.c` I have to traverse the ir and  get `!dbg !9` from `call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata !{i32* %a}, metadata !7), !dbg !9`.

BTW, there seems no difficulty when dealing with global variable since `llvm.dbg.gv` contains the very info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that we could use the static method `DbgDeclareInst* findDbgDeclare(const Value *V)` in `DbgInfoPrinter.cpp`,which can be seen [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/DbgInfoPrinter_8cpp_source.html#l00097)

It's also not very difficult to hack this piece of code^_^

Comment: Nice job. But how you can get the same for globals? For me findDbgGlobalDeclare is not working properly...Because I don't have no llvm.dbg.gv in my bytecode

Answer (score -1):

The version of my llvm is 3.3. There are not the function `DbgDeclareInst* findDbgDeclare(const Value *V)`.
What's your llvm's version?

Comment: AFAIK, llvm2.9 still has `DbgDeclareInst`; llvm just changes too much:-)