# llvm get global definition line number

Tags: llvm

I followed the [How to get variable definition line number etc. using dbg metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852180/how-to-get-variable-definition-line-number-etc-using-dbg-metadata) in order to get the line number definition for local variables (allocas), which works fine. But I need the same for globals. So I tried to hack the `findDbgGlobalDeclare()` method from http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/DbgInfoPrinter_8cpp_source.html#l00062 . However, I have no `llvm.dbg.gv` in my bytecode, so there is no dbg info to extract. I compile my target code using `clang++ -O0 -g -emit-llvm Test.cpp -c -o Test.bc` . Some samples from my bytecode:

```
@r = global i32 3, align 4
%4 = load i32* @r, align 4, !dbg !942
...
%a = alloca i32, align 4
%1 = load i32* %a, align 4, !dbg !939
```

However, I do have:

```
!924 = metadata !{i32 786484, i32 0, null, metadata !"r", metadata !"r", metadata !"", metadata !841, i32 19, metadata !56, i32 0, i32 1, i32* @r} ; [ DW_TAG_variable ] [r] [line 19] [def]
```

with on which `!0` is indirectly dependent and there is `!llvm.dbg.cu = !{!0}` .

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps are as follows:

```
1. NamedMDNode *NMD = M->getNamedMetadata("llvm.dbg.cu");
```

Then get into the metadata nodes chain till the desired global declaration.

```
2. DIDescriptor DIG(cast<MDNode>(NMD->getOperand(i)));
3. DIDescriptor DIGG(cast<MDNode>(NMD->getOperand(NMD->getNumOperands()-1)));
4. DIDescriptor DIGF(cast<MDNode>(DIGG->getOperand(0)));
5. Value* VV = cast<Value>(DIGF->getOperand(i));
6. DIDescriptor DIGS(cast<MDNode>(VV));
```

At this point, do:

```
7. DIGS->getOperand(j)
```

and check http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html#c-c-front-end-specific-debug-information for all the fields you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `!llvm.dbg.cu` is the right place now. Quoting from the source-level debugging document:

> Compile unit descriptors provide the root context for objects declared
>   in a specific compilation unit. File descriptors are defined using
>   this context. These descriptors are collected by a named metadata
>   !llvm.dbg.cu. They keep track of subprograms, global variables and
>   type information.

Specifically, see ["Global variable descriptors".](http://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html#id13)

The code you found is to support the older metadata nodes which are still generated by dragonegg so the readers support them for backwards compatibility. New LLVM code generates `!llvm.dbg.cu`.